# Can't figure out how to have my markers re-open once the application has been restarted.

Tags: java, android, google-maps, sharedpreferences

this project is to create a garden nav app. I use google maps and have implemented a longClick that opens an intent putting extra information from another class with title and snippet of their choice.

```
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
            Intent edit = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
            edit.putExtra("location", latLng);
            MapsActivity.this.startActivityForResult(edit, EDIT_REQUEST);
        }
    });
```

The class called looks like this:-

```
    public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);


    final LatLng latlng = (LatLng) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("location");

    final EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    final EditText snippet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.snippet);
    Button botton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    botton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latlng);

            if (title.getText() != null) {
                marker.title(title.getText().toString());
                marker.snippet(snippet.getText().toString());
            }

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
            resultIntent.putExtra("marker", marker);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

}
```

im really new to Java development, and have done most of this project through guides, and a lot of googling. My next problem is to be able to close the application and open it with the custom marker with the snippet and title still there? If anyone would be kind enough to walk me through this relating it to my code that would be brilliant, thanks in advance.

Comment: You tagged your question with `SharedPreferences`. Therefore, you already know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Sqlite or SharedPreferences to store the data you need in the onPause, onStop, or onDestroy method, and retrieve it onCreate or onResume.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) is a SharedPreferences Tutorial.